# Kendo UI Chart Format Date in Shared Tooltip

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, tooltip

I'm using Telerik Kendo UI Chart for Angular to create a StockChart.I'm using a shared tooltip with the default template. But, the date inside this default tooltip is shown as `mm/dd/yyyy` and I want to change this format to something like `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

So, How I change the date format inside a Shared Tooltip ?

My code with the tooltip :

```
<kendo-stockchart>
      <kendo-chart-tooltip [shared]="true" format="{0:N1}">
      </kendo-chart-tooltip>
....
</kendo-stockchart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ToolTip template](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SharedTooltipTemplateDirective/) where both the category and series are available for each point and customize the displayed values accordingly, e.g.:

[DOCS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/tooltips/#toc-shared-tooltip-customization)

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rv4m9p?file=app/app.component.ts)

Use the Intl service or other means to format all values as desired:

[DOCS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/internationalization/parsing-and-formatting/)

[API](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/internationalization/api/IntlService/)

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rv4m9p-mbjjx7?file=app/app.component.ts)